# How can I apply a psuedo-class selector to an element

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply my psuedo-class style myself?

For example, consider:

```
button {
  color:#fffff;
}
button:hover {
  color:#ddddd;
}
```

Is it possible to 'apply' the hover pseudo-class in this example so that the style would apply even if the user is not hovering over it? Conceptually something like:

`<div class='button:hover'></div>`

The constraint is that it is not possible to copy-paste the hover style, nor is it possible to edit it.

Is it possible to do this? (I'm also using SASS by the way)

Comment: Are you saying that you can't modify the CSS sheet?

Comment: @Paulie_D I am not allowed to modify the style, but I', free to create more styles.

Comment: If you can add more styles then just add the `button` style again but using the hover declarations at the end of the stylesheet. The cascade would do the rest.

Comment: Why don't you create another class for it, you can give multiple classes to one element. You need `.` to declare a class in CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D `The constraint is that it is not possible to copy-paste the hover style`

Comment: That makes no sense...do you have access to the CSS stylesheet or not?

Comment: @Secret hey I know it's been a long time since you asked this question, but if you are only looking to copy and paste the hover style from the dev tools I suggest you look at the edit I made to my post. If I'm misunderstanding your question still you can feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since u said that new classes can be added to the element.
add a class `.btn-hover` and use the following style.

```
.btn-hover{
color:#ddddd !important;
}
```

here `!important` is the key to modify the style it overwrites all the existing styles

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to add a pseudo-class selector at run time so that you can edit the css style rules for a given pseudo element then the following will work.

End goal. Copy and paste the pseudo element rule like so.

[image]

**Sidenote** There was a comment above about why you would want to do this (if this is what the OP wants) if you have access to the stylesheet.  Even if you have access to the stylesheet finding a style that you haven't written or even have written and forgot about can be a pain.  You would have to search .parent div:hover but you might not know that and there might be a lot of div:hover rules on your page making searching a pain.

### Chrome

**Dev Tools**
If you're using chrome you can bring up the chrome dev tools `ctrl`+`shift`+`i` or if you're on a mac `cmd`+`shift`+`i`. Then on the elements tab of the chrome inspector right click on the element, click on force element state then click :hover and you should be able to toggle the hover state on the right hand side in the styles tab.

[image: Chrome Toggle Pseudo Class ex.1]

In Chrome there is another alternative where you select in element in the same fashion as before and go over to the styles tab on the right hand side then click 'Toggle Element State' and you can toggle pseudo classes for the given element.

[image: Chrome Toggle Pseudo Class ex.2 step 1]

[image: Chrome Toggle Pseudo Class ex.2 step 2]

### Firefox

**Inspector**

Right click on element preferably the one you want to set the pseudo element on.  Navigate to the inspector tab right click on the element you are editing the pseudo element rule on and toggle on the pseudo element you want. Then you can go over to the rules tab and edit the style how you see fit.

[image: Firefox Inspector Toggle Pseudo Class ex.2]

**Firebug**

Right click on element then select inspect with Firebug. Open the HTML tab left click on the element that has the CSS pseudo class rule applied to it then go over to the style tab (on the right). Click the style tab's dropdown and select the pseudo element you want to toggle. You can now see the css pseudo class rule in the style tab, and edit it.

[image]

Firefox's inspector will toggle off the hover state element when you click on another element. It even does this when right clicking an element so if you want to set multiple pseudo classes on different elements I suggest Chrome or Firebug.  Chrome and Firebug on the other hand will continue to stay hovered until you toggle it back off by opening the menu again and re-clicking force element state :hover. This will allow you to edit the hover state style rules as well as copy it from the styles tab. If you want to overwrite existing hover state rules then you will want to copy and paste the style rules that are already applied and either move your stylesheet below the stylesheet that rule is refrencing or modify the rule to have a higher [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer I don't see why it got downvoted. If the OP is looking for a way to quickly edit/test or copy paste the styles this is probably one of the best techniques to do.  I use it all the time for those purposes. Although if the OP is intending for the hover to just always be on as soon as the page loads as a style this does not work. It depends on what the OP was asking.